# Transform doing a zoom on picture on Safari (iOS)

Tags: css, safari, transform

The problem is on iPhones, on android mobiles it code works well. On Safari the background picture is zoomed, you can see this on the picture below:

Display on Safari:
[Safari-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J26q.png)

Display on Android(properly):
[Android-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STMSI.png)

What can I improve with that code?

HTML:

```
<div id="background">
     <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <hr />
     <h3>Dolor sit amet</h5>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#background{
height: 92.5vh; 
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-animation: mymove 16s infinite;
animation: mymove 16s infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-timing-function: linear;
background-image: url("gallery/DSC03389n.JPG");
}

@keyframes mymove {
0%{background-image: url("gallery/DSC03389n.JPG");}
46%{background-image: url("gallery/DSC03389n.JPG");}
54%{background-image: url("gallery/DSC03385n.JPG");}
100%{background-image: url("gallery/DSC03385n.JPG");}
from { background-position: 17% 0; }
to { background-position: 70% 0; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

#background{
    background-image: url("gallery/DSC03389m.JPG");
}
  @keyframes mymove {
0%{background-image: url("gallery/DSC03389m.JPG");}
46%{background-image: url("gallery/DSC03389m.JPG");}
54%{background-image: url("gallery/DSC03385m.JPG");}
100%{background-image: url("gallery/DSC03385m.JPG");}
from { background-position: 17% 0; }
to { background-position: 74% 0; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `background-attachment: fixed;` and has been around for a really long time and is super frustrating since `cover` and `fixed` are incredibly common CSS background parameters.

The solution here is to nix the `fixed` on Safari.

What we did was add a device and browser class to our body with PHP, and set its own CSS declaration

```
.ipad #background,
.safari #background {
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
```